# conditional coloring in grep

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep

I have a simple `bash` script. One line of my script matches a "pattern" with grep and colors the match

```
grep -i --color=always -- "$1"
```

I need to modify it, so that it only colors the match, if the line is not a comment (i.e. if it does not start with a `#`). In other words: I still want grep to match the commented line, but without coloring it.

Let's say I have following text file (with added line numbers)

```
1 aaa PATTERN
2 bbb ccc PATTERN ddd
3 # eee PATTERN
4 fff ggg
```

I need my grep expression to match lines 1,2,3 but only color the lines which are not commented (1 and 2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `GNU grep` with `-P` option:

```
$ grep PATTERN file | grep -P '^[^#]*\KPATTERN|^'
aaa PATTERN
bbb ccc PATTERN ddd
# eee PATTERN
```

`\K` causes all thing in the left of `PATTERN` don't include in matched string. This solution assumes that your `grep` is aliased to `grep --color=auto`

Comment: is it possible to modify the expression `grep -P '^[^#]*\KPATTERN|^'` to use `egrep` and to match two patterns, i.e. '(PATTER1|PATTERN2)' ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to have `grep` do conditional coloring in this manner. It can only highlight the "PATTERN" that it's matching.

Answer (score 1):

just a small hack:
`grep -E 'PATTERN' <filename> | grep --color -E "^[^#]*|$" -`

you can use this: first `grep` matches the lines with PATTERN and second `grep` colors lines that does not start with '#'.

I don't think `grep --color` can do conditional coloring.

Comment: This will color the whole line instead of `PATTERN` only.